# Why does changing the text of a UILabel not reset text attributes on iOS 13?

Tags: ios, swift

On iOS 12, if one changes the text of a UILabel it resets the text attributes. On iOS 13 however, text attributes such as color, typeface, letter spacing, et cetera are kept when the text is changed. What has changed?

An example:

```swift
label.text = "Hello world"
let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: label.text ?? " ")
attributedString.addAttributes([.foregroundColor: UIColor.red], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: attributedString.length))
label.attributedText = attributedString        
label.text = "What's up world" // Text is red on iOS 13, default black on iOS 12.
```

Comment: I don't know, but I would have expected the iOS 13 behavior, to take the attributes that was at the start of the text. It's not recommended to mix `.text` and `.attributedText`, since the `.font`, `.textColor` and other properties might changes, to be more "synchronized".

Comment: Unclear what kind of answer would satisfy you. You have already answered the question What has changed? What more would constitute an answer?

Comment: I understand how it works on iOS 12, but I do not understand how it works on iOS 13. It does not immediately make sense to me how the code will behave on iOS 13 if I apply different attributes to different parts of a text, and then change the text to a text of a different length. An answer would explain the logic behind how the attributes are kept and applied to the new text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like from iOS 13, **if you set and attribute to the entire text**, it will persist! If you don't apply the attribute on the entire range of the text, it behaves like before.

You have some options to get around it:

1. Not applying it on the entire range (Happens most of the times):

```
attributedString.addAttributes([
    .foregroundColor: UIColor.red,
    .backgroundColor: UIColor.green
], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: 3))
```

2. Perform a version check (Maybe with a little extension)

```
@available(iOS 13.0, *)
extension UILabel {
    func setTextWithoutAttributes(_ text: String) {
        // Get rid of the holding attributes instance as Asperi mentioned or in another way you like
        self.attributedText = nil
        // Set the text
        self.text = text
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You did not reset `attributedText`, but documentation says - **if set, the label ignores the properties above** (see below for `UILabel.h` interface, in obj-c it is more correctly visible):

```
@property(null_resettable, nonatomic,strong) UIColor     *textColor UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR; // default is labelColor
...

// the underlying attributed string drawn by the label, if set, the label ignores the properties above.
@property(nullable, nonatomic,copy)   NSAttributedString *attributedText API_AVAILABLE(ios(6.0));  // default is nil
```

so behaves as specified (before it might be a bug, that now is fixed)

The solution of your case should be

```
label.attributedText = attributedString        
...
label.attributedText = nil      // << reset to default !!
label.text = "What's up world"
```

Comment: The doc for `text`: "Assigning a new value to this property also replaces the value of the attributedText property with the same text, although without any inherent style attributes. Instead the label styles the new string using shadowColor, textAlignment, and other style-related properties of the class.". It looks like the new behavior is buggy?